# Auto change option value in PHP/MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
$MethodLocationFrom =mysql_query("
    SELECT DISTINCT Location_From AS 'locationFrom'
    FROM trip 
");
    echo "<form action='confirmation.php' method='post'>";
    echo "<select class = 'LocationFrom' size='1'  name='locationFrom' id='locationFrom'>";
    while($check = mysql_fetch_array($MethodLocationFrom))
{
echo "<option value='" . $check['locationFrom'] . "'>" . $check['locationFrom'] . "</option>";
}
echo"</select>";

$MethodLocationTo =mysql_query("
    SELECT DISTINCT Location_To AS 'locationTo'
    FROM trip
");
    echo "<select class = 'LocationTo' size='1' size='1'  name='locationTo' id='locationTo'>";
    while($check = mysql_fetch_array($MethodLocationTo))
{
    echo "<option value='" . $check['locationTo'] . "'>" . $check['locationTo'] . "</option>";
}
echo"</select>";
```

[image: output of the code]

Hi guys! I'm making a shuttle reservation system, I'm having trouble with the option boxes, what I want to do is when I select a place from Location from (first option box) that location would automatically be remove in the location where I want to go (second box) How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me have a go, with a personal twist

assume the result of iteration to be (reduced for brevity)

```
<select id="locationFrom">
  ...
  <option value="$from">($from)</option>
</select>
<select id="locationTo">
  ...
  <option value="$to">($to)</option>
</select>
```

I assume the values of each option-set are the same.

let's get dirty with javascript. Mind you, this is long and has no comments, review it, test it and give me feedback if you find an error.

```
// script.js
(function(){
  var selectFrom, selectTo, unsetChild, nextSibling,
    onSelect, removeOption, recoverOption,
    loadWin, unloadWin;
  onSelect = function () {
    var idx = this.selectedIndex;
    if (idx !== -1) {
      if (unsetChild) {recoverOption();}
      removeOption(this.options[idx].value);
    }
  };
  removeOption = function (value) {
    unsetChild = selectTo.querySelector('[value="'+value+'"]');
    nextSibling = unsetChild.nextSibling;
    selectTo.removeChild(unsetChild);
  };
  recoverOption = function () {
    nextSibling
      ? selectTo.insertBefore(unsetChild,nextSibling)
      : selectTo.appendChild(unsetChild);
    nextSibling = unsetChild = null;
  };
  loadWin = function () {
    selectFrom = document.getElementById('locationFrom');
    selectTo = document.getElementById('locationTo');
    selectFrom.addEventListener('change',onSelect,false);
  };
  unloadWin = function () {
    selectFrom.removeEventListener('change',onSelect,false);
    selectFrom = selectTo = nextSibling = unsetChild = null;
  };
  window.addEventListener('load',loadWin,false);
  window.addEventListener('unload',unloadWin,false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out a jQuery solution (tested in Google Chrome):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function jqyHideSelectedOption(objSelect) {
  var strIDSeleted = objSelect.id;
  var strID2Handle;
  if(strIDSeleted == "locationFrom")
  {
    strID2Handle = "#locationTo";
  }
  else
  {
    strID2Handle = "#locationFrom";
  }
  strIDSeleted = "#" + strIDSeleted;
  //
  // show all options: ie, restore default settings.
  //
  jQuery(strIDSeleted + " option").show();
  jQuery(strID2Handle + " option").show();
  //
  // hide some options in the corresponding select:
  //
  var selectedCity = jQuery(strIDSeleted).val();
  if(jQuery(strID2Handle).val() == selectedCity) {
    jQuery(strID2Handle).val(null);
  }
  jQuery(strID2Handle + " option[value='" + selectedCity + "']").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).hide();
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//
//...
//
$MethodLocationFrom = mysql_query("
    SELECT DISTINCT Location_From AS 'locationFrom'
    FROM trip 
");
echo "<form action='confirmation.php' method='post'>";
echo "<select class = 'LocationFrom' size='1'  name='locationFrom' id='locationFrom' onchange='jqyHideSelectedOption(this)'>";
while($check = mysql_fetch_array($MethodLocationFrom))
{
  echo "<option value='" . $check['locationFrom'] . "'>" . $check['locationFrom'] . "</option>";
}
echo"</select>";

$MethodLocationTo = mysql_query("
    SELECT DISTINCT Location_To AS 'locationTo'
    FROM trip
");
echo "<select class = 'LocationTo' size='1' size='1'  name='locationTo' id='locationTo' onchange='jqyHideSelectedOption(this)'>";
while($check = mysql_fetch_array($MethodLocationTo))
{
  echo "<option value='" . $check['locationTo'] . "'>" . $check['locationTo'] . "</option>";
}
echo"</select>";
//
//...
//
?>
</body>
</html>
```

For the from city #locationFrom select, an onchange='jqyHideSelectedOption(this)' is used.
When a city is selected in this select, we hide this city name in the list of #locationTo select. If we choose another city, the hidden city is again shown in the destination list, so again available for destination selection.

If a destination is chosen, this city will be hidden in the from cities list.

We don't remove any option from the 2 select's, but rather temprarily hide it, as it's useful if another city is selected, and must be present for customer's selection.

Comment: This works, but it only works on the initial option and when I change the locationTo option box (first box) the locationFrom option box (second box) does not update, how to keep it updating everytime?